# NestJs Cache Manager issue

Tags: node.js, redis, nestjs

I'm having trouble when trying to use cache-manager by NestJS,
the problem is the value always return `true`,

```
const isSet = await this.cacheManager.store.getClient().set(key, value, 'EX', ttl, 'NX')
console.log("isSet => " + isSet)

if(isSet === true) {
  try {
      //do smth
  } catch(err) {
     console.log("err => " + err)
     throw err;
  } finally {
    //await this.cacheManager.del(key);
  }
}
```

my question is, when using redis-cli, when i repeatedly do

```
set key val ex ttl nx
```

if not exists, it returns OK, but when exists it returns nil.

[image]

Why does cache-manager keep returning true?

Depedency Version

```
"cache-manager": "^3.6.0",
"cache-manager-redis-store": "^2.0.0",
```

Comment: didn't you missed the `await` in that `.set` call? I believe that it returns a Promise

Comment: @MicaelLevi shoot, thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try it:

```js
const isSet = await this.cacheManager.store.getClient().set(key, value, 'EX', ttl, 'NX');
const actualValue = await this.cacheManager.store.getClient().get(key);

if(actualValue === value) {
  try {
    //do smth
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("err => " + err);
    throw err;
  } finally {
    //await this.cacheManager.del(key);
  }
}
```